# Не работает отправка данных из формы методом POST

Tags: php, html

Есть простейшая форма:

```
<form method="POST" action ="http://localhost/PhpProjectTest/newEmptyPHP.php">
            <input type ="text" name ="login">
            <input type ="submit" value ="submit" name ="submit">
 </form>
```

в файле-обработчике есть простейший код:

```
    <?php $login=$_POST('login');
    echo $login; ?>
```

Но почему-то все это не работает. При введении данных в форму, и отправке их меня пересылает на пустую страницу. В консоли выдает ошибку 500.
И более того, есть еще одна проблема: если после пересылки посмотреть исходный код документа, на котором я оказываюсь, то там после тега `Body` ничего нет. Пустота. Все, что идет после второго скрипта польностью отсутсвует на странице. Пробовал ДО него, вписывать `echo "hello"`, работает, а после него нет.

Answer (score 5):

$login=$_POST('login'); О_О
почему не $login=$_POST['login'];
это все таки массив.

Comment: Я сейчас смеюсь истерическим смехом, потому что я 2 часа искал ошибку, трижды проклял какие-то неведомые настройки браузера, а на самом деле, все дело просто в невнимательности.... Да, первый урок программиста извлечен: Если что-то не работает, не спеши винить в этом конфигурацию системы,  и настройки... Спасибо большое, конечно, все заработало.